# Why is self superfluous for a method when using bottle in a class?

Tags: python, class, bottle

I usually use `bottle` in a naked script:

```
import bottle

@bottle.route('/ping')
def ping():
    return "pong"

bottle.run()
```

It works fine, a call to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/ping` returns `pong`. I now want to use a class for the same functionality:

```
import bottle

class PingPong:
    @bottle.route('/ping')
    def ping(self):
        return "pong"

    def run(self):
        bottle.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = PingPong()
    p.run()
```

A call to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/ping` now returns a `500` and the traceback on the server is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 1732, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
TypeError: ping() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Dec/2015 19:15:15] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 500 745
```

If I remove `self` from the method definition the server works fine.

Why is the self parameter superfluous in this case?  How is that different from a normal method where self is passed by default and corresponds to 'no parameters' in the call of the method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because bottle does not know that the function you have passed is a method, it has no notion of methods. Also, ask yourself: should bottle automatically create instances?

If you want to use a bound instance method, do this instead:

```
class PingPong:
    def ping(self):
        return "pong"

    def run(self):
        bottle.route('/ping', callback=self.ping)
        bottle.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = PingPong()
    p.run()
```

That is, pass the bound method to `route()` once the instance has been initialized.

Comment: I understand, thank you. Is this equivalent to decorating the method (without `self`) with `@staticmethod`?

Comment: @WoJ: from a certain point of view, yes, it's equivalent. However there's a huge difference between static methods and instance methods